# overflow css property not adding horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css

In the following code, the elements on the right stack up on the elements on left when the page size is reduced. I have used `overflow:scroll` property but that doesn't seem to be working. How can I add scrollbar in the page.

```css
#login-link,
#signup-link {
  color: white;
  margin-right: 10px;
  align-self: center;
}

#top-level-container {
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.three-row-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: [nav-row-start]auto [nav-row-end logo-nav-row-start] auto [logo-nav-row-end content-row-start] auto [content-row-end];
}

.logo-nav-grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 50fr 50fr;
}

.nav-style {
  height: 5vh;
  /*make nav div take 5% of space of viewport*/
  background-color: #222426;
}

.logo-nav-style {
  height: 20vh;
  /*make logo-nav div take 20% of space of viewport*/
  /*background-color:#BCBBBB;*/
}

.nav-flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
  align-items: center;
}

.generic-flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.logo-nav-left-flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.logo-nav-right-flexbox-container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

#logo-nav-left {
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

#logo-nav-right {
  grid-column: 2/3;
}

.content-style {
  height: 75vh;
  /*make content div take 75% of space of viewport*/
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.selected-button {
  background-color: #F48024;
  /* Orange */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

.unselected-button {
  background-color: #BCBBBB;
  /* gray */
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}

#nav {
  grid-row: nav-row-start/nav-row-end;
  margin: 0px;
}

#logo-nav {
  grid-row: logo-nav-row-start/logo-nav-row-end;
  margin: 0px;
}

#content {
  grid-row: body-row-start/body-row-end;
  margin: 50px;
}

#profile-pic {
  margin: 5px;
}

#mail-icon-pic {
  margin: 5px;
}

#stats-icon-pic {
  margin: 5px;
}

#logo-image {
  /*the max width and max height rule will make the image fit inside the div. If the image is bigger than div, the image will
     contract, if the image is smaller than the div, the image will expand*/
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#welcome-header {
  color: gray;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#about-header-div,
#how-works-header-div {
  background-color: #BCBBBB;
}

#about-header,
#how-works-header {
  color: white;
  /*background-color:#BCBBBB;
     height:50px;
     margin:0px;*/
}

body {
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- add list of tags here in meta data -->
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">
  <title>some title</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="top-level-container" class="three-row-grid-container">
    <div id="nav" class="nav-style nav-flexbox-container">
      <!--a href="javascript:void(0)"> <img id="stats-icon-pic" src="stats_icon.png"></a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img id="mail-icon-pic" src="mail_icon.png"> </a>
      <a href="javascript:void(0)"><img id="profile-pic" src="example_profile_pic.png"> </a-->
      <span><a id="login-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Login</a></span>
      <span><a id="signup-link" href="javascript:void(0)">Sign Up</a></span>
    </div>
    <div id="logo-nav-div" class="logo-nav-style logo-nav-grid-container">
      <div id="logo-nav-left" class="logo-nav-left-flexbox-container">
        <img id="logo-image" src="example_logo.png">
        <button type="button" class="selected-button">ABCDE</button>
        <button type="button" class="unselected-button">PQRS</button>
        <button type="button" class="unselected-button">Profile</button>
      </div>
      <div id="logo-nav-right" class="logo-nav-right-flexbox-container">
        <button type="button" class="unselected-button">PQRS NEW</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="content" class="content-style">
      some content
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

reproduced by isherwood

I suppose what I am trying to do is make the page non-responsive. As I am using `css-grid` and `flexbox`, it seems they make the page responsive by default. I want to use them as they are a great help in layout.

[image]

Comment: I see scrollbars. The horizontal one is disabled since it doesn't need to scroll to accommodate anything. I don't see anything "stacking up" in Edge (Chromium Version 80.0.361.23 (Official build) dev (64-bit)) on Windows 10 or Chrome Version 79.0.3945.88 (Official Build) (64-bit) on Windows 10.

Comment: Does [this demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/e24fncu1/) show the problem? You might need to revise to explain better.

Comment: @isherwood - yes. As the window becomes smaller,the `PQRS New` button goes on top of `Profile` button. Thanks for reproducing the issue. i have added the pic in the question

Answer (score 0):

You should use a container and to put in all the overs divs for `overflow:scroll` because you are not able to use it for `body tag`. Also you can use `html {overflow:auto;}` in your css.

Answer (score 0):

You can make some changes for body css like this.

```
body { margin: 0px; overflow-x: scroll; min-width:556px; width:100%; }
```

min-width, you can define as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose what I am trying to do is make the page non-responsive. As I am using css-grid and flexbox, it seems they make the page responsive by default. I want to use them as they are a great help in layout. I enclosed the entire code in `div` and gave body width of 1300px and that seem to have worked. I'll be happy to accept other answers.

```
<div id="non-responsive-div">

<div id="top-level-container" class="three-row-grid-container">
...
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
body{
width:1300px; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following CSS for body

```
 .body {
      margin: 0 auto;
      overflow-x: auto;
      overflow-y: auto;
        }
```